# Access to embedded WPF controls in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

Lets say I got the following user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl">
    <tk:DataGrid>
        <tk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <!-- some columns -->
        </tk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </tk:DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

Actually, I can't define what columns the data grid should have, since I need to use this control in many places, with different columns. Here is what I want to do:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyPanel">
    <ui:MyUserControl>
        <Columns>
            <!-- columns that will go into the data grid -->
        </Columns>
    </ui:MyUserControl>
</UserControl>
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

P.S: DataGrid.Columns is readonly, it is not possible to bind it to something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can expose a [depenency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) on the `UserControl` called `Columns` which can bind to an internal `DataGrid`. You would access the property via `<ui:MyUserControl.Columns>` of course.

Comment: I tried something similar, however, binding to DataGrid.Columns is not possible. DataGrid.Columns is read only, binding is not allowed. I think what I want to do should be possible in code, however, I want to achieve this in a more simple/clean way, and via xaml (only) if possible.

Comment: If it cannot be bound you can attach a [`PropertyChangedCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx) where you register the dependency property, in this callback you then can manually clear the internal DataGrid's columns and add the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

As @H.B. said in his solution, you should expose your own dependency property, but just performing binding wouldn't work, since the `Columns` property is read-only.

What you need to do is handle this in your dependency property's `OnChange` callback and add/remove columns as necessary. You'll also need to register to your dependency property's `CollectionChanged` event and possibly the grid's Columns `CollectionChanged` as well to synchronize the two properties.

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a XAML-only solution for this.